# Angular, Javascript: Incrementing value with different speed

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create a loading number value but want a different speed depending on where the number is:

```
1-50, speed of 35ms
50-100, speed of 100ms
```

but I can't seem to get the logic down for it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ltyru-wexk8x?file=app%2Fprogress-bar-determinate-example.ts,app%2Fprogress-bar-determinate-example.html,app%2Fprogress-bar-determinate-example.css

```
const incr = 1;
progress = 0;
      ngOnInit() {
        setInterval(() => this.manageProgress(), 35 )
      }
    
      manageProgress() {
        if(this.progress === 50) {
          this.progress = 0;
        } else {
          this.to100();
         
        }
      }
    
    to100(){
      if(this.progress === 100) {
    
      }
      else{
        this.progress = this.progress + incr;
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the current interval and start interval again.

The next code change the interval after progress=50 and reset progress when progress=100.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.manageProgress(), 35)
  }
  interval: any;
  manageProgress() {
    this.progress = this.progress + incr;


    if (this.progress == 50) {
      clearInterval(this.interval)
      this.interval = setInterval(() => this.manageProgress(), 100)
    }

    if (this.progress == 100) {
      this.progress = 0;
      clearInterval(this.interval)
      this.interval = setInterval(() => this.manageProgress(), 35)
    }

  }
```